# How did Chadwick Boseman voice T'Challa in What If...?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, behind-the-scenes, marvel-what-if-2021

Chadwick Boseman is credited as the voice of T'Challa in S01E02 of *What If...?*, which was released August 18, 2021, but Boseman passed away August 28, 2020.

Was the recording done prior to Boseman's death? Or was some other technique used to provide the voice?

Comment: During the 20th century the time span between filming a movie and releasing it to theatures incrased greatly with much more time sprent in post production and with studios h choosing strategic times to release the movies for more profit.  So a time span of a year or two between filming scenes and the release of the movie should not be uncommon today.  The time lag between filming and release is usually shorter for tv shows but not always.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[The recording was done prior to Boseman's death](https://screenrant.com/marvel-what-if-chadwick-boseman-final-recording-details/) with at least some of the last sessions over Zoom calls. It was the last production he voiced.

> [Chadwick] really enjoyed the idea of being able to play this slightly different version of T’Challa. The events are so extremely different, but the galaxy doesn’t change T’Challa; T’Challa changes the galaxy. There are a few more times where he pops up briefly in a couple other episodes, so we were able to record with him a little bit during the pandemic. Those records were over Zoom calls, and in the last record, when we were done, I, selfishly, was able to tell him how much I personally thought of him… He touched his heart and he was very thankful, but we had no idea he was going through what he was going through.